# Errors in color resources

Tags: android, xml, colors, android-resources

I'm getting lint errors attempting to use color resources. According to the documentation, the following should be valid.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <color name="actionbar_title"></color>
</resources>
```

But this gives "Attribute is missing the Android namespace prefix". Amending to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <color android:name="actionbar_title"></color>
</resources>
```

clears the error but in a layout file the following definition

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/title"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
          android:textColor="@color/actionbar_title" />
```

gives the error "error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'textColor' with value '@color/actionbar_title').

Any and all help will be appreciated.

EDIT:
As pointed out by type-a1pha, the above did not specify a color - I've copied from a test version. However

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <color android:name="actionbar_title">#ffffff</color>
</resources>
```

gives the lint warning

```
Unexpected text found in layout file: "#ffffff"
```

but the color resource is still not recognised in the layout xml file.

Comment: what about replacing android:name with name?

Answer (score 2):

You need to actually define the color:

```
<color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
```

that is, give its hexadecimal code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<color name="actionbar_title"></color>
```

the color is empty i see.

```
<color name="actionbar_title">#000000</color>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put your file under "values" folder instead of the "color" folder.